# Openshift 2.0 Port forward mongodump Closed explicitly

Tags: mongodb, openshift

We were trying to dump our MongoDB from openshift 2.0 unfortunately we are getting the following error:

> " Mongod Failed: error reading from db: Closed explicitly"

Until a week ago this worked fine.

We have approxametly 7000 heavy referenced documents.

May its possible that openshift is closing our connection because the collection is to big?

Comment: Can you clarify which version of OpenShift you are talking about?

Comment: We are talking about openshift 2.0 also edited it in the description

Comment: @HannesMarks - Can you please share exactly what commands you use after you have enabled port forwarding?  I have done this:  `oc port-forward mongodb-14-xxxxx 34000:27017` which returns `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:34000 -> 27017` and then I tried `mongodump --port 34000 --username userXXX --password "xxxxxxx"` which returns `Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.`

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a problem from openshift. Now it is working without a problem again. Thank you.